# My suggested edit was rejected, and the post was changed to the suggested edit

Tags: discussion, questions, edits, suggested-edits

I've now [suggested an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3413030), and it was rejected.
It really not a big deal, but something seems strange.

2 reviewers approved it, one rejected it (community?), and when I looked at the post, it was edited with my suggestion! (it's even the same comment word by word..) what has happened here?

Comment: does seem strange to me

Comment: Ah, nostalgia, the reason for my very first meta post.

Comment: I can't explain why it happened, but what happened is your edit was merged with the OP's edit when the OP edited his post after you submitted your suggested edit.  Beyond that, there's not much to offer as I don't think I got a clear answer at the time

Comment: I've put a bounty on my old question to see if we can get an answer to this.

Comment: Not sure at all it's the same case as the suggested duplicate - look at the timestamps - I've suggested the edit more than 3 minutes before the OP, and been approved by two reviewers.

Comment: @Yosi It's the same case. Your edit was [rejected at 23:10:13Z](http://i.imgur.com/NMWlHXw.png). The OP's edit was made [at the same time](http://i.imgur.com/T7xQX3r.png).

Comment: @JonathanHobbs - Yeah now I see.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards the problem here isn't the race.  That happens all the time.  The issue is that the Yosi's edit was merged with the OP's